# How can programmatically configure the @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to find the way to programmatically set the "basepackages" of the "@componentScan" .

I have something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "cl.pagefoo.controller")
public class MyConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    ...
}
```

I want something like:

```
class foo extends Something{
    void init(SomethingContext sc) throws Exception{
          sc.setComponentScan("cl.pagefoo.controller");
    }
}
```

I want to find this theorical "something" class who allow to configure the controller package in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `WebApplicationInitializer` to programmatically create application context.

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
       AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

       ctx.scan("com.package.name");
       //the rest of initialization
    }

 }
```

This is an alternative way to configure web application, so you no longer need `web.xml`.

More reading:
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/how-to-use-springs-webapplicationinitializer/

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

.1. You can actually specify a placeholder :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "${mypackages}")
public class MyConfig {
    ...
}
```

However, you will have to populate the placeholder value early enough, ideally through say a system property (`-Dmypackages=somepackage`)

.2. If you have a limited number of package names you can try with Spring profiles

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package1")
@Profile("profile1")
public class MyConfig1 {
    ...
}

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package2")
@Profile("profile2")
public class MyConfig2 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me very good options I going to read about them.